# How can I measure page speed of the pages that appear after login

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I want to measure the page response time of multiple views in my application. The views are accessible only after the SSO login. the URLs of the views are not directly accessible as these are behind the login. So my question is how can I measure the speed using google page speed insights?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could run lighthouse in your local machine.

Comment: I know this is tagged as Google Page Speed, but another option would be to use WebPageTest.org with allows for signing into the system. It also reports on the new core vital metrics in the same was as Lighthouse (I *believe* it actually runs a Lighthouse test in the background itself). If you use their API you could run the test and then parse only the Lighthouse response data.